# Django-registration and django-profiles

Tags: python, django

I've installed Django-registration succesfully with [this tutorial.](http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/)

Now I want, that when Users are registrated and are logged in, they have to get on their own profile page, were they could fill in some other forms.

How do I link/use this to the [Django-profiles?](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/) (from te same developper as django-registration)

I'm quite new in this, so all help is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: go and read [django-profiles: The Missing Manual](http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/06/27/django-profiles/) this is what you need

Comment: Thank you!
But from what do they start in this manual? (from what project/app?)
They talk about "Now access /profiles/edit/" but where do I find this?